# Prove that if x ∉ B and A ⊆ B, then x ∉ A

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am an undergraduate student and I am wondering if the strategy and the writing of this proof are correct. Please help me!

***Prove that if x ∉ B and A ⊆ B, then x ∉ A.***

Assume that x ∉ B and A ⊆ B, then by the definition of subset, every element of A is element of B and every element of B is element of A.

Therefore, if x is not an element of B, x cannot be an element of A. Then, x is not an element of A. Q.E.D.

**Thanks for your help! I did not see that if A ⊆ B, not necessarily B ⊆ A.**

*Here is my new proof. Please give me your comments.*

**Proof by contradiction.**

Assume that x ∉ B, A ⊆ B, and x ∈ A.

As A ⊆ B, every element of A is an element of B.

We have assumed that x is an element of A, but x is not an element of B, what is a contradiction.

Therefore, x is not an element of A. Q.E.D.

Comment: "...then by the definition of subset, every element of A is element of B and every element of B is element of A..." is an incorrect statement.  That corresponds to $A=B$, or equivalently stated $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$  Instead the correct statement is $A\subseteq B\Leftrightarrow (x\in A \Rightarrow x\in B)$, "every element of A is an element of B**.**"

Comment: It is not true that every element of $B$ is an element of $A$. Try proceeding by contrapositive.

Comment: It may still be better to approach via contrapositive or contradiction (contradiction seems easier, fewer cases).  Else you might accidentally use circular logic or not fully explain a step.  "...if x is not an element of B, x cannot be an element of A..." was exactly the statement you were trying to prove, so it requires more explanation than that.

Comment: Might be relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition , that is: $P\rightarrow Q \iff ¬ Q \rightarrow ¬ P$

Comment: @Miguelgondu Thanks! I posted a new answer. Please give me your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to be less chatty and more to-the-pointy: Let $x$ be an element with $x\notin B$. Suppose that $x\in A$ and try to arrive at a contradiction. Since $A\subseteq B$ it now follows that .... Boom, contradiction. Hence ....

Fill in the blanks.